# Автоматически заменить текущую дату на 13 дней назад на нескольких *sql текстовых файлов

Tags: sql, windows, bat

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, что делать в такой ситуации, каждое утро мне приходится на текстовым (*txt) файле заменять текущею дату на 13 дней назад, а на других на 2 дня назад и этих (*txt) файлов очень много и я не успеваю до автоматизации этих справок. А можно ли создать бат файл и там перечислить этих sql (“1.sql”, “1-.sql”, “2.sql”, … “3653.sql”) файлов и внутри них указать строку даты, который надо менять каждый день. Ну, если можно тогда на эту дату каждый день добавить 1 день. Здесь, например, указано data = '17.12.2011' в него надо добавить +1, то есть 17+1=18. и тогда data = '18.12.2011'

Вот пример: 1.sql файл

```
(SELECT round (float (sum (kolpp)) / float (sum (kolm)), 3) * 100 "Проц. реализ.",round (float (sum (pkm)) / float (sum (kolpp)), 1) "Сред.дальн."FROM expbd.nsrezdWHERE ((expbd.nsrezd.tipv <> ' ' AND expbd.nsrezd.tipv <> 'М')
```

-- указываем нужную дату: '00.00.0000 dlya sutki' AND data = '17.12.2011')

Answer (score 1):

Вполне возможно, что есть какой-то родной для SQL способ выполнения вашей задачи. Если же ограничиться только пакетными скриптами Windows, то нужно составить список обновляемых файлов, просканировать его и заменить прошлое время на нужное. Например, есть некий файл sql.txt, который содержит слово DummyTimeStamp, и мы хотим поместить на место этого слово другое - 01.01.2012. Тогда пишем пакетный файл replace.bat для замены подстроки в текстовом файле

```
@echo offSETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONSSETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSIONif "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOFfor /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (    set "line=%%B"    if defined line (        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X    ) ELSE echo.)
```

Запускаем на выполнение так (предположим скрипты лежат в папке SQLScripts)

```
FOR /R C:\SQLScripts\ %%G IN (*.sql) DO replace.bat "DummyTimeStamp" "01.01.2012" %%G
```

P.S. Проще подобную задачу решить в PowerShell.